# Как сделать вывод названия регионов на Яндекс-Картах?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, yandex-maps-api

Делаю отчет в `Excel`, для наглядности начальникам вставил в `WebBrowser` Яндекс.Карты с окрашиванием наших Area (зон) в соответствующий цвет в зависимости от значений некоторых параметров (Зоны - несколько регионов в совокупности, например Поволжская зона - "Кировская область", "Нижегородская область", "Пензенская область", "Республика Марий Эл", "Республика Мордовия", Зона Москва - Москва + Московская область).

[image: Скриншот из Excel]

Сейчас при нажатии на регион выплывает балун (на скрине) с пустым описанием. Как мне сделать вывод на балун название данной Зоны + значение ее параметра (в соответствии с которым и происходит окрашивание), на которую был сделан клик? С js не знаком, к сожалению.

Ниже привожу код генерируемой в `vba` `html`-страницы данной карты:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://www.contoso.com/ -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Direction Yandex map.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml?modules=regions" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">

        <!-- функция возврата индекса массива для работы в дохлых версиях IE -->
        (function(A) {
            A.indexOf = A.indexOf || function(object) {
                for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (i in this && this[i] === object) {
                        return i; } }
                return -1;
            };
        })(Array.prototype);

        <!-- Выводим зону Поволжья и закрашиваем -->
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
            map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(104, 65), 3);
            var zoom = new YMaps.Zoom();map.addControl(zoom);map.enableScrollZoom(true);
            YMaps.Regions.load("ru", function (state, response) {
                if (state == YMaps.State.SUCCESS) {

                  var shapes, polygon;
                  var regionVba1 = response.filter(function (obj) {
                  var names = [
"Кировская область", "Нижегородская область", "Пензенская область", "Республика Марий Эл", "Республика Мордовия"
                  ];
                  return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
              });
              for (var i = 0; i < regionVba1.length; i++) {
                  shapes = regionVba1[i].metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
                  for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
                      polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
                          shapes[ix].coords,
                          shapes[ix].levels
                      );
                      polygon.setStyle({
                          polygonStyle: {
                              fillColor: "b00c0c50",
                              strokeColor: "b00c0c"
                          }
                      }); 
                      map.addOverlay(polygon);
                  }
              }


                 <!-- Выводим зону Москва -->
                  var shapes, polygon;
                  var regionVba2 = response.filter(function (obj) {
                  var names = [
"Московская область"
                  ];
                  return (names.indexOf(obj.name) > -1);
              });
              for (var i = 0; i < regionVba2.length; i++) {
                  shapes = regionVba2[i].metaDataProperty.encodedShapes;
                  for (var ix = shapes.length; ix--; ) {
                      polygon = YMaps.Polygon.fromEncodedPoints(
                          shapes[ix].coords,
                          shapes[ix].levels
                      );
                      polygon.setStyle({
                          polygonStyle: {
                              fillColor: "00800050",
                              strokeColor: "008000"
                          }
                      }); 
                      map.addOverlay(polygon);
                  }
              }

                } else {
                    alert ("Error: " + response.Error.Message)
                } });
        })
    </script></head>
<body><div id="YMapsID" style="width:990px;height:455px"></div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем то, что я хотел, но в принципе дело решается [созданием всплывающей подсказки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-hint-docpage/), куда можно поместить любой текст и через `vba` добавлять параметр после названия выбранной зоны (может кому-нибудь пригодиться):

```
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(45, 54), {hasHint: true});
placemark.name = "Поволжская зона";
map.addOverlay(placemark);
```